# Passing NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace to NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs fails

Tags: c#, inotifycollectionchanged

On custom property setter I try to call my custom event and pass `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace` as parameter for the `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` but I get an `System.ArgumentException`.
What i'm doing wrong?

my custom event :

```
public event EventHandler<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs> MyEntryChanged;

protected virtual void OnMyEntryChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var handler = MyEntryChanged;
    handler?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

and my call :

```
private TValue _value;

        public TValue Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(_value, value)) return;
                _value = value;
                OnMyEntryChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace));
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Argument `Replace` requires you to specify the old item and the new item.
Simply invoking it without any items will cause this exception.

In your case you could invoke it like this:

```
if (Equals(_value, value)) return;

int indexOfPreviousItem = 0; //wherever you store your item
TValue oldItem = _value;    
_value = value;
OnMyEntryChanged(
    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
        NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, 
        value, 
        oldItem,
        indexOfPreviousItem));
OnPropertyChanged();
```

Comment: @user6625158 I just noticed a typo in my code, it should work now.